# In memory zip data inflate

Tags: c, zip, inflate, in-memory

I have some compressed data in memory, I would like to know the best approach to unzip the same in memory? I find all methods available are dealing with files. How to do the same in-memory. Language I am using is C.

Comment: Are you using a library to unzip/inflate or your own code? if so what language are you writing this in?

Comment: Hi Bhavik, thanks for quick response. I am using C language. I found few library but all has functions to zip/unzip a file archive. I am writing one client that receives zipped data from the server as part of TCP payload.Looking for a way to uncompress it in memory.

Comment: Please provide the first 100 bytes of an example stream in hexadecimal, so that we can see what it is.

Answer (score 1):

That's what [zlib](http://zlib.net/) is for.  It's interface is in C.  Though it is not clear what the format of your compressed data is, zlib will handle zlib, gzip, and raw deflate data directly.

Your data, which begins with `78 5e`, is a zlib stream.  (It is not zip, nor gzip.)  You can use `uncompress()` or `inflateInit()` / `inflate()` / `inflateEnd()` from zlib to decompress that data.

Comment: I am sorry, missed to mention language :) I went through zlib, I learned it can be used for gzip. Can we use it for zip? Thanks.

Comment: you aren't looking for "zip" which is a structured data, you are looking for zlib as you are interested in "stream" compression, not "file structure"

Comment: Hi nrathaus, can it be possible to use compression algorithm for zip for a stream, or it's only for file archive?

Comment: It is highly unlikely that the zip format is being used in a stream.  Please provide the first 100 bytes of an example, so that we can see what is actually is.

Comment: Hi Mark, Here are the first 100 bytes in hexadecimal:

5e78 947d b2c9 36ab 8610 22ef f0d9 d914
2953 7933 dc5a 8485 c804 8046 6c18 6760
0fb0 b066 64cd bc33 de53 3e31 66e7 a458
b572 4afc 25dd fff5 ff55 edfa 2fdb fc7f
79fe d620 f589 8a9b 9f5d 4468 3e05 a2fe
251c 7904 5548 a141 6066 1020 4464 ef55
406c da2c 1fed b931 52be 300b 426c 8606
c203 8529 1d0f 0188 af56 67d4 2552 b7a4
214a b59a 654c e2b7 9092 de66 5971 0598
14a6 75fc a471 3fc8 8340 d17a 03b0 3a11
8630 28f0 38e2 eb8c 3a48 04cc 555b 777a
f8eb 1556 e851 0456 e26b bf59 b8be 6777
e2e1 8b83 0836 9d23

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Mark, above data's endianness is in host byte order and it's not from network traces. Data received from server is stored in a file and hexdump command on that file is used to get this data.

Thanks much for your time.